# RStudio Connect pastes CSS in cell on update

Tags: css, r, shiny, rsconnect

I am making an application regarding holiday requests. The frontpage of the app looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see in the bottom right there is a column called "Accepted?" which either shows "OK" or "DENIED" in a corresponding color. When I would accept the request it will show the following:

[image]

As you can see the CSS is pasted without actually formatting the text within. This does not happen when I run the application locally, only on the server. Once I reload the page it will show correctly again:

[image]

What exactly causes this issue? Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `renderTable` try adding `sanitize.text.function` to it

```
output$table1<- renderTable({
   data()
}, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```